# Value of EKF when fusing two estimates of the same state

Tags: estimation, state, ekf

I'm looking at fusing the output of two SLAM packages.

In the examples code given an EKF is referenced for this fusion but I can't find the implementation.

I don't understand the value of the EKF approach here vs using a simpler approach like you use when you have multiple estimates of the same state but with different variances. From what I understand this turns into basically a weighted sum, weighed by the variances.

Could someone shed light on this?

Comment: "In the examples code given" -- please _edit your question_ to _cite your reference_, or to _include a link_.  Without knowing the context of what the author was saying, there's not much we can do here.

Comment: I am having problems accessing the source,

Comment: I know ekf is used as it's the name of a function call but the details are hidden unfortunately

Comment: I started an answer and -- this is just too weird.  Instead of trying to fuse the results of two independent SLAM systems you should be running the outputs of all the sensors into one, larger SLAM algorithm.  Otherwise you get into all sorts of problems with frames of reference and how the landscape mapping is expressed, and knowing what each algorithm is doing in detail.

Comment: I can upload the function calls but yeah I felt it was odd too, I don't know what would be the prediction vs correction steps if both algorithms do the exact same thing.

Comment: Couldn't you run maximum likelihood though assuming you have the variances of each prediction?